# Sencha touch 2 - Blank white screen on startup of Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to create an MVC "Notes" application using Sencha touch 2 on aptana studio 3, I've only created the main view and a controller, but when I test it using chrome, all it shows is a blank white screen. 
Any help?

Here's my code:
Main View:

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.view.NotesListContainer", {
     extend: "Ext.Container",
     config: {
         fullscreen:true,
          items: [{
              xtype: "toolbar",
              docked: "top",
              title: "My Notes",
              items: [{
                  xtype: "spacer"
              }, {
                  xtype: "button",
                  text: "New",
                  ui: "action",
                  id: "new-note-btn"
              }]
          }]
     }
});
```

controller:Notes.js:

```
Ext.define('NotesApp.app.controller.Notes',{
     extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
     config:{
          refs:
              {
                     newNoteBtn:'#new-note-btn'
              },
              control:
                 {
                     newNoteBtn: {
                            tap: 'onNewNote'
                     }
                 }
     },
     onNewNote:function()
           {
              console.log("onNewNote fn");
           }
});
```

app.js:

```
Ext.application({
    name: "NotesApp",
    controllers: ["Notes"],
    views: ["NotesListContainer"],

    launch: function () {
           console.log("fff");
           //debugger;
           var notesListContainer = Ext.create("NotesApp.view.NotesListContainer");
           Ext.Viewport.add(notesListContainer);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the Web Inspector ?

Answer (score 1):

Recently there have been some issues with Chrome (version 43) causing white screens on chrome and android. You can try to override Ext.util.PaintMonitor to return a new instance of Ext.util.PaintMonitor.CssAnimation as specified [here](http://codesmith.in/sencha-overflow-error-chrome-android/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but if you define

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.view.NotesListContainer", {
extend: "Ext.Panel",
```

you have to OK. If not post here your **index.html**

Cheer, Oleg

Answer (score 0):

H, please only you change into `Ext.Application`

```
views: ["NotesListContainer"],
```

to,

```
requires: ['NotesApp.view.NotesListContainer'],
```

**Hope these helps. :)**